# UnoWinUI DockPanel control

Tags: uno-platform

The below DockPanel code works fine in the UNO UWP Project, but breaks in unoapp-winui.

```
xmlns:Custom="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls" 

<Custom:DockPanel Margin="0,5,0,0" LastChildFill="True">
```

Is there any toolkit available in Uno WinUI which supports DockPanel?

Thanks

Neeraj

Answer (score 0):

WCT (Windows Community Toolkit) for WinUI 3.x is [not yet released](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/milestone/22).

Uno Platform team is working closely with WCT's team to ensure it's released on all platforms at once.

But you can try the [pre-release version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Uno.CommunityToolkit.WinUI) published on NuGet.